# Initializing a struct containing function pointers in C

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers, c89

The struct `box`is defined in `box.h` as such:

```
typedef struct box {
    int (*func1) (const void *p1, const void *p2);
    void (*func2) (void *p3);
} Box;
```

`box.c` includes `box.h` and has the following function:

```
int create_box(int (*func1)(const void *p1, const void *p2), void (*func2)(const void *p3), Box **box) {
```

`create_box` is called to initialize a box based on the provided parameters. I'm struggling to figure out how to assign the provided function pointers to the fields of the structure. First, I start out by allocating memory to `**box` via `(*box) = malloc(sizeof(Box));`

But then I try to assign the arguments of the function pointer through

```
(*box)->func1 = (func1)(&p1, &p2);
(*box)->func2 = (func2)(&p3);
```

Running this tells me that all of my pointers are undeclared. Clearly there's something I'm misunderstanding about how function pointers work, but I don't understand how I'm supposed to initialize them (if that's the write word). I've tried replacing the right side with `(*func1)(*p1, *p2)`, `(func1)(p1, p2)`, `(*func1)(p1, p2)`, `(*func1)(&p1, &p2)`, etc. but they haven't yielded anything that I can understand. How do I properly initialize this structure's function pointers?

I'm working in C90 if that's relevant.

Comment: Maybe `(*box)->func1 = func1;`?

Comment: note that `p1` and `p2` in type declaration are not needed. I mean `int (*func1)(const void*p1, const void *p2)` means the same as `int (*func1)(const void*, const void *)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if I well understand

```
(*box)->func1 = (func1)(&p1, &p2);
(*box)->func2 = (func2)(&p3);
```

is in `int create_box(int (*func1)(const void *p1, const void *p2), void (*func2)(const void *p3), Box **box) {` so you wanted :

```
(*box)->func1 = func1;
(*box)->func2 = func2;
```

The form `(func1)(&p1, &p2);` calls the function whose address is in *func1* with the address of *p1* and *p2* in argument (the "()" around *func1* is useless) and this is visibly not what you want and can do because *p1* and *p2* are not defined.

But `(*box)->func2 = func2;` is not possible with your current code because the signature of `(*box)->func2` and `func2` do not correspond. You can change the second argument of `create_box` to be `void (*func2)( void *p3)` or to modify the *struct box* to have `void (*func2) (const void *);`